# Allow read, write and execute files from asp.net web page using IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, curl, iis-7

I am going to host external site (not in domain). I have used IIS7 and given access to anonymous access to all users. I have login screen and only users who successfully login will get access to another page (Page2.aspx). All these users are in database.

In Page2.aspx, I am creating one xml file which will be saved in server drive. After writing success, I am reading one API exe (curl.exe) file which will send the xml file info to another site. If anything wrong, it writes to log.txt file which is also in same folder of website.

Everything works if I run locally.

It looks like, it has no permission to read/write and execute the file. I have given permission to Network Service, Anonymous access to read/write and execute file but no luck.

Could you please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to give permissions to the IIS_IUSRS group or the IIS_IUSR user on the server.  IIS 7's default set up is to run the application pool using the ApplicationPoolIdentity which typically means either of the previous roles / users.  Only if the administrator has changed the default to the Network Service will that account ever be touched.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It helped a lot for writing xml file and also to read and write log.txt file. But my exe file didn't run. Is there any other permission or extra things need to be done?

Comment: Try setting Load User Profile to true inside the application pool's advanced settings.  If you're calling an executable, make sure to read this post: http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/archive/2005/12/02/startprocessasuser.aspx

Comment: I am calling using the code                                                            Process PPPP = Process.Start("D:\curl.exe -v -k -u " + applicationID + " -X POST --upload-file " + memeberInfoXMLFile + " https://api.prontoforms.com/api/1/data/dispatch.xml");

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder that you want your users to have access to and add the user **IUSR** with the needed permissions